# Redux, actions, authorization

Tags: authorization, redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently using **redux** and **redux-thunk** middleware.

When it comes to controls regarding action dispatching, such as:

- does the user have sufficient permissions for this action?
- prompt the user to confirm his action (*for destructive action*)

I believe placing such controls inside async actions (*thunk*) is the way to go, because:

- it keeps my code DRYer (*many components/views could trigger the
  action, whereas there is only one actionCreator for said action*)
- it's the last point before "something happens" in the app. Making it feel like a strategic place to make such controls.

**The question(s)**

1. I'm looking for feedback from other redux users. I'm fairly
   confident of this decision, but having little feedback (*and being
   junior dev*) makes me doubt. Is this the right way to go for
   *authorization* controls when using redux?
2. What about making the *authorization* controller into
   **middleware**. It would keep auth controls in a single place instead of duplicating it in every actionCreator.
   **Edit** 
   *When digging deeper into this possibility it quickly became challenging because middleware initially only receive `(dispatch, getState)` meaning that an authorization middleware would need to "know" which action is being dispatched (or which actionCreator is being used), something that required a hacky-ish setup and eventually proved un-reliable.*

**Other points**

- Yes, this is client-side. Yes, we also make server-side checks.
- I know that these types of controls should NOT be in my store/reducers. They need to be pure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are good to go with your setup. Thunk is a good way for orchestrating your program-flow. There are also other Middlewares like redux-saga which is a bit more sophisticated but as far as i understand you want to do something like this (pseudo code)?

```
function authorizeAndTriggerAction(forUser) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return authorizeUser().then(
      action => dispatch(concreteAction(forUser)),
      error => dispatch(notAuthorized(forPerson, error))
    );
  };
}
```

This can be done with thunk.

Comment: Yep, that’s what we recommend. This, or something like Redux Saga for complex workflows.